# Pivot with unknown row result

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

to make my problem simple, let's say I have two tables: `users` and `cars`, that have a many-to-many relation (one user can have many cars, and one car can be of many users):

```
tbl_users          tbl_user_car                      tbl_cars
-------------      ----------------------------      ------
id_usr | name      id_usr_car | fk_usr | fk_car      id_car | name 
1      | usr1      1          | 1      | 1           1      | car1
2      | usr2      2          | 1      | 2           2      | car2
3      | usr3      3          | 2      | 1           3      | car3
```

I have a web CRUD that admin could associate cars to users, so I don't know how many cars has an user. So I want to make a query that shows the user and all its associated cars but like a pivot, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM pivot
------
name_usr | id_car | name_car  | id_car2 | name_car2 | ... n number of cars
usr1     | 1      | car1      | 2       | car2      | ...
usr2     | 1      | car1      |         |           | ...
usr3     |        |           |         |           | ...
```

I tried to use `crosstab()` function but I need to know how many columns I want to return, and I need to make 5 inner join to see more data. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: How about just putting the values into an array?

Comment: Sorry, I have not enough level in PostgreSQL, so at the moment I don't know how to make it with arrays. Could you show me a workaround using arrays as you said, please?